# Moving large vb.net app from 3.5 to 4.5 .net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to move a fairly large vb.net application from .net 3.5 framework to 4.5. I've removed the old referenced files and replaced them with the latest versions. There are still references however to the old versions of these files visible in the object explorer (e.g., System.Code [2.0.0.0] & System.Code [4.0.0.0]). How do I get rid of these?

Comment: System.Core?  Object Browser does not tell you which assemblies actually get used in a project.  Browser state is saved, so liable to remember which assemblies used to be in the list previously.  Manually removing is not necessary, just change the "Target framework" setting, Project > Properties > Application tab.  Intentionally targeting an 8 year old and discontinued framework version is not a great idea, pick ~4.7.2

Comment: I removed all references then added newer ones back so the object browser It shouldn't remember any assemblies. Agreed 4.5 is old but 3.5 is older.

Comment: It remembers assemblies it once displayed, browser state is saved.  The obvious and intuitive answer to what you see.  It is not a problem.